# Trocar Fragments Android

Tags: java, android, xml

Bom gente, estou começando com Android Studio e estou desenvolvendo um pequeno app e fiz um menu, e gostaria que quando eu clicar nele, abra outro fragment.
Tentei várias coisas já
e nada :/

A última foi essa

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    if (id == R.id.Aries)
    {
      fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new Aries())
         .commit();
    }
```

Mas onde está o "new Aries tenho o erro de "cannot find symbol fragment_aries"

O meu app será de horóscopo, e depois farei a conexão com banco de dados online.

Qualquer ajuda nessa parte também, agradeço

Obrigado

Attt

Lucas Soares

[image: MainActivity]
[image: Quando abro o fragment]

Comment: Você pode adicionar códigos da sua classe `Aries` ?

Comment: Estava com erros, porém segui o passo a passo da resposta do amigo e resolvi tudo. E agora estou com esse problema de sobrepor o fragment ps: não consigo visualizar a resposta do usuário que me ajudou

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer a transição entre os fragments na MainActivity com o NavDrawer, eu uso assim:

```
   public void displayView(int viewId) {

        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (viewId) {
            case R.id.fragment_1:
                fragment = new Fragment1();
                title  = "Fragment 1";
                break;
            case R.id.fragment_2:
                fragment = new Fragment2();
                title  = "Fragment 2";
                break;

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    }
```

Espero ter ajudado. Pode ver mais [aqui](https://github.com/albertohugo/NavDrawerSimple).

Answer (score 1):

Eu faço da seguinte forma: Primeiro vou instanciar um listener para os itens do menu clicados.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //OUTRAS IMPLEMENTAÇÕES

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);mNavigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            selecionarOpcaoMenu(menuItem);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Depois eu implemento o método que trata o evento do clique.

```
private void selecionarOpcaoMenu(MenuItem menuItem){
    mOpcaoSelecionada = menuItem.getItemId();
    menuItem.setChecked(true);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

    String titulo = menuItem.getTitle().toString();

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if(fm.findFragmentByTag(titulo) == null){
        Fragment primeiroNivelFragment = new Fragment();

        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.conteudo, primeiroNivelFragment, titulo)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Espero tê-lo ajudado, tenho um exemplo de navegação com fragments caso queira dar uma olhada. [Aqui](https://github.com/Turbiani/Navegacao)

Answer (score 0):

### Para uma nova Activity(Atividade):

Crie uma nova `Activity` com o nome de `MainActivity2` e insira este código abaixo em seu método `onNavigationItemSelected` de sua `MainActivity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class); 
startActivity(intent);
```

---

### Para um novo Fragment(Fragmento):

Crie um novo `Fragment` com o nome de `sobreFragment` e insira este código abaixo em seu método `onNavigationItemSelected` de sua `MainActivity`:

```
sobreFragment fragment = new sobreFragment();
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTrasaction =
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTrasaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTrasaction.commit();
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, segui tudo e consegui abrir o fragment, porém ele está abrindo e mostrando o conteúdo da minha MainActivity por baixo  Onde saberia dizer onde errei?